# sed variable replacement

Tags: bash, string, sed

I have tried this countless ways, time to throw in the towel and ask the master...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read in the VERSION.header file, this is a plain text file
# with returns, which in some of my tests, I am loosing the returns and getting
# one string wrapped only by the shell width
VERSION_HEADER=`cat VERSION.header`

sed 's/_VERSION_HEADER_/"$VERSION_HEADER"/g' DOCUMENTATION
```

The string '_VERSION_HEADER_' exists currently as line 1 in the file DOCUMENTATION.  The file 'VERSION.header' has about 18 lines in it.

I am not attached to using sed.  All I am looking to do is read in a file which acts as a template, store that files data as a variable, read in a second file, store it as a variable.  Look in the second file for a marker, replace the marker with the data from the first file.

Example:

$cat VERSION.header

```
hi, this is my header file, how are you today
good, that is nice, great
have a nice day, k, thx, bye.
```

$cat DOCUMENTATION

```
_VERSION_HEADER_

# This is a documentation file, please read it
# If you do not read it, you will get stuck to the toilet.
```

And the result should be:

hi, this is my header file, how are you today
good, that is nice, great
have a nice day, k, thx, bye.

# This is a documentation file, please read it
# If you do not read it, you will get stuck to the toilet.

Comment: What is the result you've got?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace a text with a variable (sed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297052/replace-a-text-with-a-variable-sed)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
sed -e '/_VERSION_HEADER_/{r VERSION.header' -e ';d}' DOCUMENTATION
```

That reads in the file when it finds the template string, then deletes the template string.

Comment: I get an error: sed: 1: ";d}\n": extra characters at the end of d command

Comment: @allentown: It works for me using GNU sed 4.2.1. What version do you have (and what OS and version)?

Comment: @user170579: Try it without the semicolon - some versions of `sed` don't like them.

Comment: `d` and `}` should be separate commands: `sed -e '/_VERSION_HEADER_/{r VERSION.header' -e 'd' -e '}' DOCUMENTATION`

Comment: @TobySpeight: That's not required in GNU `sed`, but it is in OS X. The only reason that I'm using `-e` in this answer is in order to have a way to terminate the file name argument of the `r` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s/_VERSION_HEADER_/$VERSION_HEADER/g" DOCUMENTATION
```

EDIT

Sorry, finally got your problem. You have a multi-line pattern. [This](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch06_01.htm#SEDAWK-CH-6-SECT-1) may help. Also consider using Python instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

f = open('doc.txt', 'r')
doc = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('VERSION.header', 'r')
versionHeader = f.read()
f.close()

doc = doc.replace('_VERSION_HEADER_', versionHeader)
print doc
```

This may be less efficient, though.

Comment: Thanks, trying to keep this in bash for now so it is portable to systems that will not always have python.

Getting err: sed: 1: "DOCUMENTATION": extra characters at the end of D command

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{s=s" "$0"\n";next}/_VERSION_HEADER_/{$0=s}1' version.header documentation
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at man 1 ed as well:

```
# http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php?id=howto:edit-ed
[[ $(grep -c _VERSION_HEADER_ DOCUMENTATION) -eq 1 ]] && \
cat <<-'EOF' | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//' | ed -s DOCUMENTATION
   H
   /_VERSION_HEADER_/i
   .
   .c
   .
   .r VERSION.header
   wq
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Using (FreeBSD) sed do something like:

```
VERSION_HEADER="$(sed -E -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' -e 's/&/\\\&/g' -e 's|/|\\/|g' -e 's/$/\\/g' VERSION.header)"

# note the space after ${VERSION_HEADER}
sed -E -i "" "/_VERSION_HEADER_/s/_VERSION_HEADER_/${VERSION_HEADER} /" DOCUMENTATION
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your text :

```
text=$( cat VERSION.header );
escaped_text=$( echo "$text" | sed 's/[/\\&]/\\&/g;s/$/\\/;$s/\\$//' )
sed "s/_VERSION_HEADER_/$escaped_text/g" DOCUMENTATION
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oneline; do
    VERSION_HEADER=${VERSION_HEADER}'\n'${oneline};
done < VERSION.header

sed 's/_VERSION_HEADER_/'"${VERSION_HEADER}"'/g' DOCUMENTATION
```