# Replace a text with a variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, sed

How can I do this?

```
sed -i 's/wiki_host/$host_name/g' /root/bin/sync
```

It will replace `wiki_host` with the text `$host_name`.
But I want to replace it with the content of the variable..

I tried it with

```
sed -i 's/wiki_host/${host_name}/g' /root/bin/sync
```

It doesn't work either.

Comment: check this: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/04/replace-string-in-file-with-value-in.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to use double quotes:

```
$ sed -i "s/wiki_host/${host_name}/g" /root/bin/sync
```

Your single quotes prevent the shell variable from being replaced with its contents.

Comment: One important caveat is that the sed delimiter (`/` in this case) cannot be part of `${host_name}`, otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: In the last case you have to use other delimiters for sed, then it works with replacement value containing slashes as well. For example
$ sed -i "s#wiki_host#${host_name}#g" /root/bin/sync