# Sed command to remove part of a string

Tags: shell, sed

I have values in txt file

> cc.cis.jms.Simulator.CAAMS=CAAM270:CAAM050

Now i want to replace the below value as

> cc.cis.jms.Simulator.CAAMS=CAAM270:CAAM050:CAAM250

I tried this:

```
SIMULATOR='CAAM270:CAAM050'
ADDEDCAAM="$SIMULATOR:CAAM250"
SACTUALVALUE='cc.cis.jms.Simulator.CAAMS='$SIMULATOR
SREPLACEVALUE='cc.cis.jms.Simulator.CAAMS='$ADDEDCAAM

sed -i 's|$SACTUALVALUE|$SREPLACEVALUE|g' $FILE >  /tmp/Bridger/CC_CISConfig.properties
```

CC_CISConfig.properties file got created in  /tmp/Bridger/ path but with no content on it.

I also tried:

```
sed -i 's|$SACTUALVALUE|$SREPLACEVALUE|g' $FILE >  /tmp/Bridger/CC_CISConfig.properties.txt
```

But didnt work out. Kindly help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace a text with a variable (sed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297052/replace-a-text-with-a-variable-sed)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `"` to substitute your bash variable values in sed expression.

It should be,

```
sed -i "s|$SACTUALVALUE|$SREPLACEVALUE|g" $FILE >  /tmp/Bridger/CC_CISConfig.properties
```

Then, You are using `-i` option. It will change the modification in original file.
But, you are redirecting STDOUT to `/tmp/Bridger/CC_CISConfig.properties`. In this case, nothing to be written to the file. That is why, you are getting empty file.

1) If you want to create a new updated file,

```
sed "s|$SACTUALVALUE|$SREPLACEVALUE|g" $FILE >  /tmp/Bridger/CC_CISConfig.properties
```

2) If you want to do the substitution in the same(original) file,

```
sed -i "s|$SACTUALVALUE|$SREPLACEVALUE|g" $FILE
```

Comment: if this answer solved your problem, mark this as accepted. more info, [click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).